# How to display Success Message

Tags: magento-1.9

I Have a form also it redirect to same page. I try to display Success message After Product add to the cart but it showing whenever i reload the page

```
  <form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::registry('current_product')); ?>" method="post" id="seller_addtocart_form1" class="ma">
                                <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $currentUrl =  Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" />
                                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId(); ?>" name="mpassignproduct_id" class="mpassignproduct_id"/>
    <?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Success');?>

    <button id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>" class="button btn-cart customaddtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?>" onclick="<?php echo $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>">
<span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Bag')?></span></span></button><div><button class="button buy-now" onclick="location.href ='{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}/checkout/cart/add?product=1&qty=1'">
<span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button></div>
</form>
```

What mistake i have done

Answer (score 1):

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Success');`
  this will not show the message you are adding the success message in session. on the refresh the page it will show message.

for displaying the success you have to set response from controller to show message.  follow that [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53797/success-error-message-on-ajax-request) for ajax success message.

Comment: on which file i have to edit

Comment: do you have get any response from after addtocart?

Comment: no i am asking which file i want to add the controllers

Comment: in which you are adding the product into cart.  there you get response either product added into cart or not.

Comment: Check this --> http://totaltoys.com/fisher-price-babys-first-bl.html  Insted of redirection i added into reload samepage it self

Comment: yes it will show the message too..

Comment: the message will show where the  global message are shown

Comment: ya but that's assign product extension how do i check please help me that

Comment: "options":2,"check":"success"  this is your response to ajax add to cart so find the ajax function that are sending the http://totaltoys.com/ajaxcart/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3RvdGFsdG95cy5jb20vZmlzaGVyLXByaWNlLWJhYnlzLWZpcnN0LWJsLmh0bWw_X19fU0lEPVU,/product/1411/form_key/daG75DRDHZixzz8y/  and add you message there

Comment: No actually i change ajax into page laod

Comment: do you submit the form? then add the message?

Comment: In controllers or phtml

Comment: let me tell how the global notification work. you submit the form and set the notification but it will not show next time you will load the page it will show after setting the notification reload the page again

Comment: No actually that's magento default global message i didn't set any message on that now i want that message on individual page itself

Comment: this is using session so for session you have  to do that

Comment: How to do it in session and where to use it